# Unable to use QFile to write directly to the disk

Tags: qt

I'm having a problem writing directly to a disk, I'm trying to write a Qt version of the old PARTCOPY (now obsolete on systems incompatible with 16-bit)

I'm using Windows 10, and have my program elevated to Administrator privileges.

Every time I try to open "\\.\A:" in with `QIODevice::WriteOnly`, I get an error message "The parameter is incorrect".

Using Visual Studio step-wise debugging, I think I've found the problem occurs in `QFSEnginePrivate::nativeOpen()` when tring to execute `CreateFile()`.

The line:

```
// WriteOnly can create files, ReadOnly cannot.
DWORD creationDisp = (openMode & QIODevice::WriteOnly) ? OPEN_ALWAYS : OPEN_EXISTING;
```

seems to be the cause. If I force the value of `creationDisp` to be `OPEN_EXISTING`, then I can get the file opened and I can write to the disk without any further problems. The issue is that I don't know what way I can get this working without using the debugger.

Has anyone found a solution to this?

UPDATE: (test case)

```
#include <QtCore/qcoreapplication.h>
#include <QtCore/qtextstream.h>
#include <QtCore/qfile.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTextStream cout(stdout, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    QFile f("\\\\.\\A:");
    if (!f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        cout << f.errorString();
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ... can you add a testcase to your post?

Comment: @peppe, I've added code that illustrates the problem I'm having.

Comment: Has it something to do with that strange path? Or just *any* file doesn't work? (Which would be a bit surprising...)

Comment: This is a Windows-specific issue. That's how you access the physical disk itself. [https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/kb/100027]

Comment: Maybe then check on the bugtracker? Sounds like a quite specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these two functions, I write successfully by (1).

1. `bool QFile::open(FILE *fh, OpenMode mode, FileHandleFlags handleFlags = DontCloseHandle)`
2. `bool QFile::open(int fd, OpenMode mode, FileHandleFlags handleFlags = DontCloseHandle)`